# Charger of laptop 110-240 V

Tags: power

I have a Toshiba laptop. The charger of my laptop says that the output is from 110-240 V.

Can I plug my charger to a 220 V without damaging it and do I still need an adapter?

I'm too scared to try it to plug it in a 220 V. I'm using 110 V all these times though.

Comment: isn't 220 lies in the range 110-240?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your charger can accept 220 V mains power. You will need an adapter because the shape of the plug is very likely different. A simple adapter doesn't do anything to the voltage, it just offers a different shape of plug. (There are adapters that change voltage, but they are larger, more expensive, uncommon, and you don't need them for a laptop.)

For example, you might have a "Type A" plug (used in the US):

[image]

and you might be trying to plug it into a French socket:

[image]

A simple adapter which should cost maybe $10 will do the job.